# Display p elements as block within an inline-block span

Tags: html, css

So I have some inline-block elements like so:

```
<span style="display: inline-block">
  <img>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some more text</p>
  <button>A button</button>
</span>
```

I want them all inline except I want the first p element positioned on top of the other one yet have both together inline with the rest of the span. From what I've been reading, it's bad practice to put a div inside a span, so what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Use a proper grid with divs and put your content inside that. Don't use paragraphs as grid structure.

Comment: When you say "on top" are you referring to overlaying the elements (like a sandwich)? You could use `position:` to pull that off.

Comment: inline elements shouldn't contain block elements.

Comment: @Dawson "on top of" meaning above, as if both p elements were block, not overlapping.

Answer (score 4):

It's not "bad practice", it's simply impossible. The browser will "correct" your HTML and it will not behave as expected.

Try using `<div style="display:inline-block">` as your container instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wild guess at what you're after based on my comment above.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
    </div>

    <div class="cell">
      <div class="table">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">
            <p>Paragraph one. Paragraph one. Paragraph one.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">
            <p>Paragraph two. Paragraph two. Paragraph two.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cell">
      <button>Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would go to all this effort just to avoid using `<table><tbody><tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>...</tbody></table>`...

Comment: Because tables are specifically and solely to be used for tabular data. This is clearly not tabular data. And because tables have limitations and quirks that make modern responsive layouts more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

As @Neit pointed out, the browser will correct the DOM when you put block-level elements inside inline elements (see first example). A `div`, or maybe a `section` is definitely a better choice both for valid and semantic markup.

Using CSS to change `display:` *does* work, but it isn't best practice (for example an `em` in place of your `span` above will render exactly the same). Certain versions of browsers will also ignore some types of `display:` changes; thus, your code would fail. So using a better container is going to provide the fewest headaches.[image]

See the code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/9mf91b1v/